# Java read XML file full of content and put into Database

Tags: java, xml, database, oracle

I have assignment to read XML file of University Schedule , there are class rooms, time , weeks, teachers and so on. And I have to read all of them and put them to Data Base. Edit: I have to read everything because that xml is messy and it is hard to recognize everything.

I am asking to you guys, because I am newb in Java and I would like if you guys will direct me in good way how to start everything, because I don't have any idea, from what I have to start.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're new to Java, I'd recommend reading a book or tutorial on Java first. Start simple - nothing to do with XML or databases. Then learn about XML. Then learn about databases. Then try to put it together. If you have specific problems when putting it together, you can ask a *specific* question here. Currently this question is way too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient way of reading xml-files with java is the [JAXB(Java Architecture for XML Binding)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxb/)

From there you could go with [JDBC(Java Database Connectivity)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)
to save your Objects into a database.

Generally your question is very broad and should be divided into further sub-questions.